# Retrieving the value of SharePoint Number List Field

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

This should be a fairly simply thing but I'm going round in circles. I'm trying to retrieve the Exchange Rate in a SharePoint Field and store it as a variable for later use, but can't find a way of doing it.

This query...

```
 var query = 
    "http://example.domain/sites/ExampleSite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/CurrencyExchangeRates?$select=Title,ExchangeRate&SortField=Exchange_x0020_Rate&SortDir=Asc"
```

...just returns the title.

Here's a screen grab for better explanation:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of the parameters you're including are incorrect.

**To specify the Order By field:**

First, instead of `SortField` use `$orderby`.

```
&$orderby=ExchangeRate
```

Notice that we use the same variation of the field name that you used in the `$select` parameter; any space characters in the field's *display name* are just dropped from the string (rather than replaced with `_x0020_` as you might find in a field's internal name).

Note: If dropping the space characters results in a naming collision between existing fields, SharePoint will allow you to differentiate between them by appending a numeral to the end of the field name, such as `ExchangeRate0` instead of `ExchangeRate`, so you might need to experiment to find the correct variation of the field name.

**To specify the Sort Direction:**

Second, instead of `SortDir=Asc` just add a space and `asc` after `ExchangeRate` in your `$orderby` parameter value.

```
&$orderby=ExchangeRate asc
```

After making those changes, your REST URL would look something like this:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/CurrencyExchangeRates?$select=Title,ExchangeRate&$orderby=ExchangeRate asc
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that URL and it still just returns the currency titles?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer SPServices. https://spservices.codeplex.com/

```
var currencyArray = new Array();

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "ExchangeRateList",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='LinkTitle'/><FieldRef Name='Exchange_x0020_Rate' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
           currencyArray.push([$(this).attr("ows_LinkTitle"), $(this).attr("ows_LinkTitle")]);
        })
    }
});
```